# redshift multiple queries on the same table at the same time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, query-optimization

If I fire multiple SELECT queries(multiple jobs) on the same table at the same time in redshift, will it degrade performance? Is copying to a temp table and dividing the queries between the original and temp table a right approach?

Comment: Amazon Redshift caches data, so it is likely to perform better with multiple queries going to the _same_ table rather than multiple queries going to _different_ tables. But, the only true way to know this is to perform some tests against your database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, as long as your data is sorted and distributed the best way for your workload it's better to query the same table as results are cached. You are fine to fire lots of SELECTs on the same table as long as you're not running other kind of statements like DELETE, UPDATE, VACUUM, ANALYZE, ALTER, UNLOAD or other I might have forgotten, that could potentially lock the table or consume too much resources.

The only real scenario where you should consider creating a copy of your table for querying is when you would benefit significantly from another sortkey and/or distkey.

But have in mind that Redshift is **not** built to handle hundreds of calls per second, non stopping, if that's what you are trying to do. If you reach the concurrency limit of the WLM queue, queries will get queued while waiting for running queries to complete and you want to avoid long queues at any cost.